# 'Binding' sólo se puede establecer en una DependencyProperty de un DependencyObject.'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Buenas, estoy tratando de que un UserControl acepte el binding de un List pero me da el error:

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Binding' no se puede establecer en la propiedad 'Stocks' de tipo 'CantidadControl'. 'Binding' sólo se puede establecer en una DependencyProperty de un DependencyObject.'

Dejo el codigo aca:

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Peluqueria_Marfil.CantidadControl" x:Name="cantidadControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Peluqueria_Marfil"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
    TextElement.FontWeight="Regular"
    TextElement.FontSize="13"
    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" 
    TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"        
    Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
    FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}">
  <Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="CBcantidad" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Seleccione Cantidad" SelectedIndex="0">
    </ComboBox>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C#

```
public List<Stock> Stocks
        {
            get { return (List<Stock>)GetValue(StocksProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StocksProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StocksProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Stocks", typeof(List<Stock>), typeof(StockControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata() {
            DefaultValue = new List<Stock>(),
            BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
            DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
            PropertyChangedCallback = new PropertyChangedCallback(PropiedadCargada)
        });


        public CantidadControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

        }

        private static void PropiedadCargada(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            /*
            int cantidad = 0;
            List<Stock> listaStocks = (List<Stock>)obj.GetValue(StocksProperty);

            foreach (Stock stock in listaStocks)
            {
                cantidad += stock.Cantidad;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(cantidad);
            */
        }
```

El pedazo de Xaml donde esta el Binding:

```
<local:CantidadControl Stocks="{Binding Producto.Stock, Mode=TwoWay}"></local:CantidadControl>
```

Gracias

Comment: En el Binding no debería ser Producto.Stocks  ? Creo que te falta la s final.

Comment: Puedes enseñarnos la clase Producto completa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira aqui:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty StocksProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Stocks", typeof(List<Stock>), typeof(StockControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata() {
            DefaultValue = new List<Stock>(),
            BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
            DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
            PropertyChangedCallback = new PropertyChangedCallback(PropiedadCargada)
        });
```

Fijate que el tercer parametro le dices que `typeof(StockControl)` es el dueño del DependencyProperty `Stocks`. Pero estas utilizando `Stocks` en el control `CantidadControl`. Tienes que definir Stocks como DependencyProperty tambien en `CantidadControl`. *De hay que diga no puede hacer binding, `Stocks` no es un `DependencyProperty` en `CantidadControl` pero si en `StockControl`*

Comment: Si me di cuenta cuando me lo remarcaste jajajaja

Comment: Me alegro que haya ayudado :D